# Use existing class with openapi-generator-maven-plugin without skipping validation

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using plugin openapi-generator-maven-plugin in version 6.3.0 and openapi 3.0.3 (yaml spec).

I want to use an existing model class instead of creating it by generator. I almost used the existing class successfully in generated api, but I had to skip the validation of spec by setting `<skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>`.

Is there a way of keeping the spec validation active?

Here is my current config which works with skipped validation:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.api</apiPackage>
                            <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                            <languageSpecificPrimitives>ArticleEntity</languageSpecificPrimitives>
                            <importMappings>
                                ArticleEntity=com.example.openapigenerator.model.Article
                            </importMappings>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.model</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>false</legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

```yaml
paths:
  /article:
    post:
      tags:
        - article
      summary: Add a new article to the store
      description: Add a new article to the store
      operationId: addArticle
      requestBody:
        description: Create a new article in the store
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArticleEntity'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArticleEntity'

components:
  schemas:
    ArticleEntity:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Article'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @tbatch 's answer further, the `typeMappings` brougth me to the following solution:

```yaml
paths:
  /article:
    post:
      tags:
        - article
      summary: Add a new article to the store
      description: Add a new article to the store
      operationId: addArticle
      requestBody:
        description: Create a new article in the store
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Article'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Article'

components:
  schemas:
    Article:
      type: object
      format: article
```

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml
                </inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.api</apiPackage>
                <skipValidateSpec>false</skipValidateSpec> <!-- My intended goal, to keep spec validation active -->
                <importMappings>
                    Article=com.example.openapigenerator.model.Article
                </importMappings>
                <typeMappings>object+article=Article</typeMappings> <!-- THIS DID THE TRICK FOR ME -->
                <modelPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.model</modelPackage>
                <configOptions>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                    <legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>false</legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me in order to have a reference to an external class for a request parameter. Instead of `importMappings` I had to use `schemaMappings` :
<schemaMappings>Article=com.example.openapigenerator.model.Article</schemaMappings>

Comment: any idea how to do this for gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Using an external model is simple.  Let's pretend we have a class called `MyExternalClass.java`.  We first need to make sure the generator knows where this class lives.  We do this with out `importMappings`.  However, we also need to tell our generator what object to replace.  This means we have to have an object to replace.  Let's create a dummy object for our schema called `MyUnusedClass`.  Our resulting schema would look like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /class:
    post:
      tags:
        - article
      summary: Add a new article to the store
      description: Get an Object
      operationId: getObject
      requestBody:
        description: get my object
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyInternalClass'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
components:
  schemas:
    MyInternalClass:
      type: object
      properties:
        date:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
```

Now we are half way there.  Your swagger documentation knows about the dummy schema that we have created.  However, your generator doesn't know about the external version of this schema.  As I explained previously, We can easily set that up with our typeMappings.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml
                </inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.api</apiPackage>
                <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                <languageSpecificPrimitives>ArticleEntity</languageSpecificPrimitives>
                <importMappings>
                    MyExternalClass=my.package.containing.MyExternalClass
                </importMappings>
                <typeMappings>
                    MyInternalClas=MyExternalClass
                </typeMappings>
                <modelPackage>com.example.openapigenerator.model</modelPackage>
                <configOptions>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                    <legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>false</legacyDiscriminatorBehavior>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that in the above maven, I have not only told the generator to import the class, but I have told the generator to replace every occurrance of `MyInternalClass` with `MyExternalClass`.

#### BONUS TIP

Even though the generator knows to replace the occurances of `MyInternalClass` with `MyExternalClass`, it will still generate java class.  This takes up space and can be confusing to other developers on your team.  To prevent this, add it to your `.openapi-generator-ignore` file.  Now it will be like the schema never existed in the first place.

Comment: The `typeMappings` did the trick for the return types. Those are now type of `MyExternalClass`, but my request body is still type of `MyInternalClass`.